# object as List<long> always return null

Tags: c#, validation, casting

I wanted to ensure the list property of my model is not empty,so i created a **ValidationAttribute**, but the **value as List< long >** always return null even if the property decorated with **NoEmpty** is of type List< long >.

why? and how to do it properly?

```
public class NoEmptyAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var list = value as List<long>;

        var msg = $"{validationContext.MemberName} can not bt empty";

        if (list == null) return new ValidationResult(msg);

        return list.Count == 0 ? new ValidationResult(msg) : ValidationResult.Success; 
    }
}
```

I updated my code,and now it works fine:

```
public class NoEmptyAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var list = value as IEnumerable;

        var msg = $"{validationContext.MemberName} can not be null";

        if (list == null) return new ValidationResult(msg);

        return list.Cast<object>().Any() ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult(msg);
    }
}
```

The reason of why **value as List< long >** always return null is that the value is of type HashSet< long >.

Comment: is the `value` equal `null` or is the type not `List<long>`?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling the method? Another possibility would be to step through the code or to replace the `value as List<long>` with a `(List<long>) value` to get the exact error message why it is not casted.

Comment: @StefanKert This code is called implicit on validating => there is no user generated code that will call it explicit

Comment: Use the debugger and set a breakpoint on `var list = value as List<long>;`. Inspect the value type when the debugger stops and you will see, why you get null

Comment: Do as Stefan said. You'll see that value isn't a List<long>, or that value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a unit test (based on the code of your NoEmptyAttribute) and everything work as expected

```
[TestClass()]
public class NoEmptyAttributeTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetValidationResult_ListLongWithElements_ReturnsNull()
    {
        object obj = new object();
        object value = new List<long> { 1, 2 };

        ValidationContext ctx = new ValidationContext( obj ) { MemberName = "Foo" };
        var noempty = new NoEmptyAttribute();
        var result = noempty.GetValidationResult( value, ctx );
        Assert.IsNull( result );
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetValidationResult_ListLongEmpty_ReturnsCannotBeEmpty()
    {
        object obj = new object();
        object value = new List<long>();

        ValidationContext ctx = new ValidationContext( obj ) { MemberName = "Foo" };
        var noempty = new NoEmptyAttribute();
        var result = noempty.GetValidationResult( value, ctx );
        Assert.IsNotNull( result );
        Assert.AreEqual( "Foo can not bt empty", result.ErrorMessage );
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetValidationResult_ListLongNull_ReturnsCannotBeEmpty()
    {
        object obj = new object();
        object value = null;

        ValidationContext ctx = new ValidationContext( obj ) { MemberName = "Foo" };
        var noempty = new NoEmptyAttribute();
        var result = noempty.GetValidationResult( value, ctx );
        Assert.IsNotNull( result );
        Assert.AreEqual( "Foo can not bt empty", result.ErrorMessage );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I figured it out and i need this attribute to be compatible for different types.

Comment: Then you should think about a renaming to `CollectionNotEmptyAttribute`